# How to save both entities of OneToMany relationship in a single call in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have two entities as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<WorkFlowStatus> workFlowStatuses;
    
    //mapping with some other tables as well
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="location_id", nullable=false)
    private Set<LocationDetails> locationDetails;
    
    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="WorkFlowStatus")
public class WorkFlowStatus {
    
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false)
    private Employee employee;

    public WorkFlowStatus() {}
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

There is `workFlowStatus_Id` column in `Employee` table which is also present in `WorkFlowStatus` table and  it's primary key of that table.
Basically I want to make new entry in `WorkFlowStatus` table first and then update `workFlowStatus_Id` column of my `Employee` table with this newly inserted entry's Id.
So I have created one method annotated with `@Transactional` in my Service layer. Also, I have `Autowired` both `EmployeeRpository` and `WorkFlowStatusRepository`. My service method looks something like:

```
@Service
public class EmpService {
 @Autowired
    EmployeeRpository employeeRpository;

    @Autowired
    WorkFlowStatusRepository workFlowStatusRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void updateEmployeeWorkflowStatus(Long empId) throws SQLException {
        //getting Emp object first
        Employee emp = employeeRpository.findById(empId);
        WorkFlowStatus workFlowStatus = saveWorkFlowStatus(emp);
        updateEmpWorkFlowStatus(emp, workFlowStatus);
    }

    private WorkFlowStatus saveWorkFlowStatus(Employee emp) {
        //create new Object
        WorkFlowStatus workFlowStatus = new WorkFlowStatus();
       //set other properties and fetched emp in created object
        workFlowStatus.setEmployee(emp);
        return workFlowStatusRepository.save(workFlowStatus);
    }

    private void updateEmpWorkFlowStatus(Employee emp, WorkFlowStatus workFlowStatus) {

        //set saved workFlow in existing emp object
        emp.setWorkFlowStatus(emp.getWorkFlowStatus().add(workFlowStatus));
        employeeRpository.save(emp);
    }
}
```

I have enabled hibernate logging. I could see that insert statements are getting generated while making insert in `WorkFlowStatus` table but no statements are getting generated while updating entry of `Employee` table. What wrong am I doing? How to make insert in first entity and then update second entity in the same call?

Answer (score 1):

In WorkFlowStatus Entity,

```
@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id", nullable=false , insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Employee employee;
```

In Employee Entity,

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = WorkFlowStatus.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id",nullable = false)
private Set<WorkFlowStatus> workFlowStatuses;
```

References :

https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

[Hibernate Spring - @OneToMany - Foreign key is not getting stored in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27162634/hibernate-spring-onetomany-foreign-key-is-not-getting-stored-in-database)

[Hibernate is inserting null value in foreign key field when saving a unidirectional one to many mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133393/hibernate-is-inserting-null-value-in-foreign-key-field-when-saving-a-unidirectio)

https://github.com/riskop/jpa_hibernate_problem_parent_id_is_not_filled_by_hibernate